# с++ Работа компаратора

Tags: c++

работал в онлайн компиляторе где версия с++ 8.3, но нужна 5.11.
При вводе это в Dev c++ где версия 5.11 компилятор ругается. Как выяснилось надо компаратор вывести отдельной функцией , как это можно реализовать?

вот мой код:

[ссылка на онлайн компилятор](https://ideone.com/T8jRxw)

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: *"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**."*

Comment: https://ibb.co/Xyf8RCS думаю от вас хотят такого

Answer (score -2, accepted):

спасибо [@goldstar_labs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193157/goldstar-labs) за ответ : https://ibb.co/Xyf8RCS

Comment: да блин, ну добавьте вы код в вопрос, я добавлю код в ответ и разойдёмся как цивилизованные люди)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, так я спасибо сказал) я уже переписал со скрина))) а код вставить пытался, но чет как-то криво вставляется